# Excel Count down Issue?

Tags: excel

I have this pivot table that produce this table,the first column is pending days which represent how long the part is requested till today the next one is part code and next to it I have Total amount of my Inventory. what I want to do is a formula that allocate a number to the fields if their total-amount is > 0.
here is where my problem lies:

[image: first]

if you pay attention to the red ones their total amount is 3 but we have four request from this part and I want for the last one instead of number 1 the formula insert #N/A so that I can Comment correctly.

like this:
[image: second]

appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Where is there a pivot table? How can a pivot table produce another table? The two screen shots are the same. What is the formula that inserts a 1? It's really hard to answer this. Please provide more meaningful information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `COUNTIF` function with a relevant and absolute reference to see whether the total amount of parts has already been reached. Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)>C2,NA(),1)
```

Broken down, this formula counts how many of the parts have already been requested and if this exceeds the total amount of parts it will return `#N/A`, otherwise it will return `1`.

Comment: Greater than B2 or C2?

Comment: Good catch! Did my test using `$A$2:A2` and `B2`, forgot to change one back. Thanks